# javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException in AES encryption

Tags: c#, java, encryption

I am using AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding padding standard in java and my friend uses PKCS7 standard in c#.NET
If My friend encrypt the data using AES and send me the key then I can decrypt it.

But If my data length increases more than 2920 bytes then if i encrypt the data in c#.NET and decrypt the data in java then my decryption does not work good.
It gives me the following error.

"javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher"

Thanks
Bapi

Comment: Googling for "Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher" gives plenty answers.

Comment: Added C# tag -- this sounds like a problem with not flushing the buffer in C# that you're then seeing in Java. You can also get round the whole padding issue by using (generally more secure) CTR mode.

Answer (score 1):

You again forgot to flush the buffers which means that the data stream is incomplete.

[EDIT] I don't know about C# but in Java, you must call doFinal() once after all data has arrived. (See [the docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#Cipher)).

The source of the problem is that the encryption API needs to know when you're done. It can't tell from the data, you must call a method to say "wrap it up, create the final checksum, whatever, so the receiver can decode it".

Answer (score 0):

just use `cipher.dofinal("Your byte array","offset...put 0","block size...16");`

```
eg : c.dofinal(ByteArray,0,16);
```